# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'http gitlab-ci runner

Tags: curl, gitlab-ci

I'm attempting to call an API from a gitlab-ci.yml file.  I'm trying to determine whether the error message is cutting off prematurely or if the curl command is not properly reading a variable from within the script.

```
leapwork:
  stage: leapwork
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - echo "Run the Schedule"
    - echo "$LEAPWORK_URL"
    - echo "$LW_SCHEDULE_ID"
    - echo "$LW_RUNNOW"
    - echo "$LEAPWORK_ACCESS_KEY"
    - partial_url=${LEAPWORK_URL}${LW_SCHEDULE_ID}${LW_RUNNOW}?api_key\=${LEAPWORK_ACCESS_KEY}
    - headerAccess="--header 'AccessKey:${LEAPWORK_ACCESS_KEY}'"
    - headerJSON="--header 'Accept:application/json'"
    - curlString="${headerJSON} ${headerAccess} '${partial_url}'"
    - echo "passed the assignment"
    - echo ${partial_url}
    - echo $headerAccess
    - echo $headerJSON
    - echo $curlString
    - run_id=$(`curl -s -S -X GET ${curlString}`)
```

This is the output generated

```
$ echo "Run the Schedule"
Run the Schedule
$ echo "$LEAPWORK_URL"
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx/api/v4
$ echo "$LW_SCHEDULE_ID"
_disguised_parameter_
$ echo "$LW_RUNNOW"
/runNow
$ echo "$LEAPWORK_ACCESS_KEY"
_api_key_
$ partial_url=${LEAPWORK_URL}${LW_SCHEDULE_ID}${LW_RUNNOW}?api_key\=${LEAPWORK_ACCESS_KEY}
$ headerAccess="--header 'AccessKey:${LEAPWORK_ACCESS_KEY}'"
$ headerJSON="--header 'Accept:application/json'"
$ curlString="${headerJSON} ${headerAccess} '${partial_url}'"
$ echo "passed the assignment"
passed the assignment
$ echo ${partial_url}
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx/api/v4/disguised_parameter/runNow?api_key=_api_key_
$ echo $headerAccess
--header 'AccessKey:_api_key_'
$ echo $headerJSON
--header 'Accept:application/json'
$ echo $curlString
--header 'Accept:application/json' --header 'AccessKey:_api_key_' 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx/api/v4/_disguised_parameter_/runNow?api_key=_api_key_'
$ run_id=$(`curl -s -S -X GET ${curlString}`)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'http
```

Any input on the error message from curl?  Is it probably that curl got the full server address with parameters and it just got cut off in the error message or did the address for the API get cut off?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: When executing the command `run_id=$(\`curl -s -S -X GET ${curlString}\`)`, try removing the backticks. I think this is leading to unexpected behavior. To capture the output of the command it should be `run_id=$(curl -s -S -X GET ${curlString})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The result was the same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the host is not known docker.

You need to add the domain name and domain ip in `extra_hosts` parameter under docker executor configuration in `config.toml`

Get the ip address of the host you are trying to add, as you need to add both hostname and host ip in `extra_hosts` parameter.

In your **config.toml**, change like this:

```yaml
[[runners]]
  name = "maven-docker"
  url = "https://<your-domain-name>/gitlab/"
  token = "MXvXVma55_Kw2o"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "maven:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    extra_hosts = ["<your-domain-name>:<your-domain-ip>"]
    pull_policy = "never"
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.custom]
    run_exec = ""
```

Then, restart the gitlab runner using command `sudo gitlab-runner restart` or `gitlab-runner restart`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a situation seemingly peculiar to running on AWS.  I had to create an entry in the security group's inbound rules to allow traffic on the specific port coming from the security group.